# How to create .jar library

Tags: java, jar

I wrote some java classes hat contain more new functions, now I want to create a java library.

All my classes are writen to add functions in an Android application, so my question is:

How i can create a java library using my java classes ?

Exist a particular procedure for Android application or i can use standard way (command line) ?

Is it a good way use this command ?

> java -jar cf myJar.jar myClass.class

What is the best way to create my jar ?

Comment: That command will only run a jar, not create it. You would need to use jar to create jars, or Maven/Gradle/Ant, etc. Or, if you're doing Android development, then you should do it within the construct of the Android SDK to ensure dependencies are handled correctly.

Comment: Maven or Gradle can build JAR files and include external dependencies. I'd say that is their number one usage

Comment: you have to use maven,  it is easier for creating jar

Comment: How i can come a generate a jar with obfuscated code to prevent decompilation ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the JDK's [built-in jar utility](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html) to create your jar file:

```
jar cf jar-file input-file(s)
```

however, beyond really small and simple toy projects, no one does that.
what you really want to do is learn about modern build systems, how they work, and how to use them.

the 2 most popular ones these days are [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) and [gradle](http://gradle.org/), and if youre after android development [gradle is probably the better choice](http://gradle.org/getting-started-android/).
its a learning curve, but its the only way to go forward.

Comment: You've missed a dash before cf

Comment: @radai i need a confirmation, if i want create  a (android) java library, is it correct wrote java classes with the function that i need and later create a jar ? There are some rules that i must respect or is not ? Could I simply jav classes ?

Comment: @Max - explaining either android development or a build system is impossible to do in a SO comment. spend some time with the gradle tutorial i linked to above, and come back to SO with specific questions when you have them, but yes. you write you code (as java files) add a build file that allows the build tool to compile that code into classes and package it into a jar.

Comment: @radai  For example: i wrote a classes that contais a code that make a speed test.

Now i need to create a library to avoid to wrote again the code and "only" recall it.

I want use this library in some project